# Склонение слов по падежам в Python

Tags: python, pymorphy2

Облазил все ссылки в гугле и яндексе и нигде нет рабочего примера склонения слов по падежам. Библиотека Petrovich / Pytrovich не подходит, т.к. склоняемые слова могут быть и не именем собственным.

Comment: Вы же сами в тегах указали pymorphy. Чем он вам не подходит? Вроде для русского языка он также работает

Comment: а пример кода есть?

Comment: https://pymorphy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/guide.html

Comment: @EzikBro `"Вроде для русского языка он также работает"` - "из коробки" он только с русским языком и работает. Поддержка других языков (украинского, белорусского, например) достигается установкой дополнительных словарей.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пример из документации pymorphy2

```
>>> import pymorphy2
>>> morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()
>>> butyavka = morph.parse('бутявка')[0]
>>> gent = butyavka.inflect({'gent'})
>>> gent.word
'бутявки'
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://pymorphy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/guide.html#inflection
https://pymorphy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/grammemes.html#russian-cases